# Can I convert *interface{} to *int using unsafe.Pointer in Go

Tags: go, type-conversion

I am making a memory pool in Go.
I am doing so because implicit converting int to interface{} will trigger a memory allocation.I want to avoid the allocation.
I want to allocate several types of pointers in one pool.
The pool is something like this.

```
type creator struct{
    buf []interface{}
}
func (cr *creator) Create()*interface{}{
    if len(cr.buf)==0{
        cr.buf=make([]interface{},256)
    }
    current:=&cr.buf[0]
    cr.buf=cr.buf[1:]
    return current
}

func (cr *creator)CreateInt()*int{
    pointer:=cr.Create()
    return (*int)(unsafe.Pointer(pointer))   // <-- right or wrong?
}
```

Is the code valid?

Comment: "Is the code valid?" No.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the idea is even valid let alone the code, unless you are trying to do something very low-level (and inherently unsafe). In any case it seems you are just using the interface as storage space (should be 16 bytes on 64-bit system I think). Why not just have a slice of

type Storage [16]

Then you can easily adjust the size if you find you need more than 16 bytes.

Comment: Sorry I meant:
`type storage [16]uint8; type creator struct { buf []storage }`

Answer (score 1):

You have `*interface {}` and you want to pretend that it is `*int`! How is that going to work?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var cr creator
    pointer := cr.CreateInt()
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", pointer) // *int
}

type creator struct {
    buf []interface{}
}

func (cr *creator) Create() *interface{} {
    if len(cr.buf) == 0 {
        cr.buf = make([]interface{}, 256)
    }
    current := &cr.buf[0]
    cr.buf = cr.buf[1:]
    return current
}

func (cr *creator) CreateInt() *int {
    pointer := cr.Create()
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", pointer)            // *interface {}
    return (*int)(unsafe.Pointer(pointer)) // *interface {} to *int
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TLF7kbYPA0M

Output:

```
*interface {} 0x452000
*int 0x452000
```

Comment: Yes,I pretend *interface{} is *int.because the size of interface{} is 16 bytes,and the size of int is 8 bytes.But I don‘t know if it is safe。In fact， I pretend *interface{} to not only *int but also several other types of pointers.These types are not more than 16 bytes

Comment: @海牙客移库, of course it is *not* safe, hence the package name.

Comment: @海牙客移库 why are you trying to pretend two things of a different size are the same? You could easily just start with a pointer type which would be the same size. Regardless, using unsafe and changing types is inherently unsafe.

Comment: @Peter. We think the "safe" differently. As you think, we can't use unsafe package anywhere.

Comment: @JimB 。 I want to create different pointers using one memory pool. This is an ordinary operation in C

Comment: @海牙客移库, but that’s not what your doing here. If you want void pointers, just use `unsafe.Pointer` . The slice of interfaces is the problem.